# "Were sorry but something went wrong" while trying to access Django application on A2

Tags: django, passenger

I have been working on deploying a somewhat existing django application on an A2 shared server. 
I have been following the following guides:
https://medium.com/@isaactchikutukutu/deploying-django2-python3-on-a2-hosting-9e786a3e38ad
https://www.a2hosting.co.uk/kb/developer-corner/python/installing-and-configuring-django-on-unmanaged-servers

Any time I try to visit my website all I get is a page that says "We're sorry, but something went wrong"
It gives me an error ID and says 
Web application could not be started by the Phusion Passenger application server.

Please read the Passenger log file (search for the Error ID) to find the details of the error.

<strike>I'm not sure where to find the Passenger log files and thus I have no idea how to figure out what isn't working properly. 
When I run manage.py it seems to run fine. I can call run server and it works fine. It would be awesome if someone could help me move forward with this. Thanks!</strike>

Alright I found the error log in cPanel here is the error I found:

```
[ E 2019-02-24 09:16:35.7928 3903346/T8p age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/joshpedo/public_html/pedowitz_com: The application process exited prematurely.
App 160091 output:   File "/home/joshpedo/public_html/pedowitz_com/passenger_wsgi.py", line 5, in <module>
App 160091 output:   File "/home/joshpedo/virtualenv/public__html_pedowitz__com/3.5/lib64/python3.5/imp.py", line 172, in load_source
```

line 5 of my pasenger_wsgi.py file is

```
import myproject.wsgi
```

The structure of my project was a bit messed up. It is fine now